# Is it possible to reorganize nested tuples?

Tags: haskell

What I want to do is something like this:

Take an arbitrary polymorphic tuple:

```
x = (((1, ""), Nothing), ('', 6))
```

And reorganize with something like this type (not necessarily in the same order but the same structure.:

```
(Int, (Char, (Maybe Int, (String, (Int, ()))))
```

I really don't know the name for this pattern so I am unable to use google to the best of my ability.

Comment: first, your x isn't quite right: the '' isn't valid Haskell. Do you mean a char space, ' '?   But yes, you can write a function that re-arranges the elements of the tuple you give: `f (((n,s),m),(c,i))=(i,(c,(m,(s,(n,())))))`     But I'm not sure that's what you're seeking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you only have to deal with this specific case, i.e., converting from

```
(((Int, String), Maybe Int), (Char, Int))
```

to

```
(Int, (Char, (Maybe Int, (String, (Int, ()))))
```

then, depending on whether you want to preserve the order of the `Int`-components or swap them, you can simply use one of these two functions:

```
from1 (((m, s), mb), (c, n)) = (m, (c, mb, (s, (n, ()))))
from2 (((m, s), mb), (c, n)) = (n, (c, mb, (s, (m, ()))))
```

---

But we can of course be just a bit more ambitious and aim for a more generic solution; see, for example, [Jeuring and Atanassow (MPC 2004)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-27764-4_4). To this end, let us enable some language extensions

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
```

and introduce a GADT for codes that we can use to represent tuple types

```
infixr 5 :*:

data U a where
  Unit  :: U ()
  Int   :: U Int
  Char  :: U Char
  List  :: U a -> U [a]
  Maybe :: U a -> U (Maybe a)
  (:*:) :: U a -> U b -> U (a, b)
```

For example, the target type from your example can now be encoded by the expression

```
Int :*: Char :*: Maybe Int :*: string :*: Int :*: Unit
```

of type

```
U (Int, (Char, (Maybe Int, (String, (Int, ()))))
```

As a convenience, we introduce

```
string :: U String
string = List Char
```

We furthermore introduce a type of explicitly typed tuple values

```
data Typed where
  Typed :: U a -> a -> Typed
```

and a notion of type-level equality:

```
infix 4 :==:

data a :==: b where
  Refl :: a :==: a
```

With that, we can define a heterogeneous equality check on tuple-type encodings:

```
eq :: U a -> U b -> Maybe (a :==: b)
eq Unit Unit                   = Just Refl
eq Int Int                     = Just Refl
eq Char Char                   = Just Refl
eq (List u1) (List u2)         = case eq u1 u2 of
                                   Just Refl -> Just Refl
                                   _         -> Nothing
eq (Maybe u1) (Maybe u2)       = case eq u1 u2 of
                                   Just Refl -> Just Refl
                                   _         -> Nothing
eq (u11 :*: u12) (u21 :*: u22) = case (eq u11 u21, eq u12 u22) of
                                   (Just Refl, Just Refl) -> Just Refl
                                   _                      -> Nothing
eq _ _                         = Nothing
```

That is `eq u1 u2` returns `Just Refl` if `u1` and `u2` encode the same tuple type, and `Nothing` otherwise. In the `Just`-case the constructor `Refl` acts as proof for the type checker that the tuple types are indeed the same.

Now we want to be able to convert tuple types to a "flattened", i.e., right-nested, representation. For this, we introduce a type family `Flatten`:

```
type family Flatten a

type instance Flatten ()           = ()
type instance Flatten Int          = Flatten (Int, ())
type instance Flatten Char         = Flatten (Char, ())
type instance Flatten [a]          = Flatten ([a], ())
type instance Flatten (Maybe a)    = Flatten (Maybe a, ())
type instance Flatten ((), a)      = Flatten a
type instance Flatten (Int, a)     = (Int, Flatten a)
type instance Flatten (Char, a)    = (Char, Flatten a)
type instance Flatten ([a], b)     = ([a], Flatten b)
type instance Flatten (Maybe a, b) = (Maybe a, Flatten b)
type instance Flatten ((a, b), c)  = Flatten (a, (b, c))
```

and two functions `flattenV` and `flattenU` for, respectively, flattening tuple values and the encodings of their types:

```
flattenV :: U a -> a -> Flatten a
flattenV Unit _                  = ()
flattenV Int n                   = flattenV (Int :*: Unit) (n, ())
flattenV Char c                  = flattenV (Char :*: Unit) (c, ())
flattenV (List u) xs             = flattenV (List u :*: Unit) (xs, ())
flattenV (Maybe u) mb            = flattenV (Maybe u :*: Unit) (mb, ())
flattenV (Unit :*: u) (_, x)     = flattenV u x
flattenV (Int :*: u) (n, x)      = (n, flattenV u x)
flattenV (Char :*: u) (c, x)     = (c, flattenV u x)
flattenV (List _ :*: u) (xs, x)  = (xs, flattenV u x)
flattenV (Maybe _ :*: u) (mb, x) = (mb, flattenV u x)
flattenV ((u1 :*: u2) :*: u3) ((x1, x2), x3)
                                 = flattenV (u1 :*: u2 :*: u3) (x1, (x2, x3))

flattenU :: U a -> U (Flatten a)
flattenU Unit                 = Unit
flattenU Int                  = Int :*: Unit
flattenU Char                 = Char :*: Unit
flattenU (List u)             = List u :*: Unit
flattenU (Maybe u)            = Maybe u :*: Unit
flattenU (Unit :*: u)         = flattenU u
flattenU (Int :*: u)          = Int :*: flattenU u
flattenU (Char :*: u)         = Char :*: flattenU u
flattenU (List u1 :*: u2)     = List u1 :*: flattenU u2
flattenU (Maybe u1 :*: u2)    = Maybe u1 :*: flattenU u2
flattenU ((u1 :*: u2) :*: u3) = flattenU (u1 :*: u2 :*: u3)
```

The two are then combined into a single function `flatten`:

```
flatten :: U a -> a -> Typed
flatten u x = Typed (flattenU u) (flattenV u x)
```

We also need a way to recover the original nesting of tuple-components from a flattened representation:

```
reify :: U a -> Flatten a -> a
reify Unit _                  = ()
reify Int (n, _)              = n
reify Char (c, _)             = c
reify (List u) (xs, _)        = xs
reify (Maybe u) (mb, _)       = mb
reify (Unit :*: u) y          = ((), reify u y)
reify (Int :*: u) (n, y)      = (n, reify u y)
reify (Char :*: u) (c, y)     = (c, reify u y)
reify (List _ :*: u) (xs, y)  = (xs, reify u y)
reify (Maybe _ :*: u) (mb, y) = (mb, reify u y)
reify ((u1 :*: u2) :*: u3) y  = let (x1, (x2, x3)) = reify (u1 :*: u2 :*: u3) y
                                in  ((x1, x2), x3)
```

Now, given a type code `u` for a tuple component and a flattened tuple together with an encoding of its type, we define function `select` that returns all possible ways to select from the tuple a component with a type that matches `u` and a flattened representation of the remaining components:

```
select :: U b -> Typed -> [(b, Typed)]
select _ (Typed Unit _)                  = []
select u2 (Typed (u11 :*: u12) (x1, x2)) =
  case u11 `eq` u2 of
    Just Refl -> (x1, Typed u12 x2) : zs
    _         -> zs
  where
    zs = [(y, Typed (u11 :*: u') (x1, x')) |
            (y, Typed u' x') <- select u2 (Typed u12 x2)]
```

Finally, we can then define a function `conv` that takes two tuple-type codes and a tuple of a type that matches the first code, and returns all possible conversions into a tuple of a type that matches the second code:

```
conv :: U a -> U b -> a -> [b]
conv u1 u2 x = [reify u2 y | y <- go (flattenU u2) (flatten u1 x)]
  where
    go :: U b -> Typed -> [b]
    go Unit (Typed Unit _ ) = [()]
    go (u1 :*: u2) t        =
      [(y1, y2) | (y1, t') <- select u1 t, y2 <- go u2 t']
```

As an example, we have that

```
conv (Int :*: Char) (Char :*: Int) (2, 'x')
```

yields

```
[('x', 2)]
```

Returning to your original example, if we define

```
from = conv u1 u2
  where
    u1 = ((Int :*: string) :*: Maybe Int) :*: Char :*: Int
    u2 = Int :*: Char :*: Maybe Int :*: string :*: Int :*: Unit
```

then

```
from (((1, ""), Nothing), (' ', 6))
```

yields

```
[ (1, (' ', (Nothing, ("", (6, ())))))
, (6, (' ', (Nothing, ("", (1, ())))))
]
```

We can make things even a bit nicer, by introducing a type class for representable tuple types:

```
class Rep a where
  rep :: U a

instance Rep () where rep = Unit
instance Rep Int where rep = Int
instance Rep Char where rep = Char
instance Rep a => Rep [a] where rep = List rep
instance Rep a => Rep (Maybe a) where rep = Maybe rep
instance (Rep a, Rep b) => Rep (a, b) where rep = rep :*: rep
```

That way, we can define a conversion function that does not need the type codes for the tuples:

```
conv' :: (Rep a, Rep b) => a -> [b]
conv' = conv rep rep
```

Then, for example

```
conv' ("foo", 'x') :: [((Char, ()), String)]
```

yields

```
[(('x', ()), "foo")]
```

Comment: Nice! Crazy overkill, but nice!

Answer (score 1):

I'm still recent to Haskell but I'd do this with a pattern-matching function.

```hs
converter :: (((Int, String), Maybe a), (Char, Int)) -> (Int, (Char, Maybe Int, (String, (Int, ()))))
converter (((i1, s), m), (c, i2)) = (i1, (c, (m, (s, (i2, ())))))
```

You of course could replace all the concrete types with type variables and it would also work.

```hs
converter :: (((a, b), c), (d, e)) -> (a, (d, c, (b, (e, ()))))
converter (((i1, s), m), (c, i2)) = (i1, (c, (m, (s, (i2, ())))))
```

(Obviously you'd want to get the types in the correct order and make sure this all compiles.)